# Selectively sort vector c++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector

I have the following vector:

```
vector<unsigned> vec = {5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4}
```

Now I want to sort this vector lexicographically by odd indices (and if odd indices are equal, then by the even indices). Such that the sorted vector "vec" is:

```
   {0, 4, 1, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6}
```

I know std::sort is going to sort "vec" entirely. Is it possible to use std::sort to sort the vector selectively. Similarly for std::lower_bound. Is it possible to find the lower_bound using odd indices only.

I want the same effect as vector of pair. For efficiency reasons I am not storing vec as vector of pair.

Comment: not really clear how you want to sort. For example, what happened to the `6` in the original vector?

Comment: @tobi303 I want to sort by even indices. Sorry for the typo

Comment: As I understand, you want a vector of pair, and sort them (and flatten the vector).

Comment: You could write your own iterator, so that when it increments it returns the next even index; but personally I'd suspect that trying to sort just the evens in the set, means the data isn't being represented very well

Comment: ok, but also after the fix I dont understand what you mean by "sort by even indices". In the sorted vector all elements changed their place, not only the ones at even indices. Looking at it again, do you maybe actually want to sort `{ {5,6}, {5,4}, {1,3}, {0,4} }` ? In that case you should sort a `vector<pair<unsigned>>`

Comment: like jarod says, you need to use pairs, because the custom sort functor that can be supplied to std::sort has no clue about indexes

Comment: @Dan this doesn't allow you to sort based on index, only on value

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I want the same effect as vector of pair, but for efficiency reasons I am not storing them as vector of pair

Comment: How is `std::pair` ineffecient?

Comment: @GillBates For large vectors after testing I found std::pair to be in efficient

Comment: @tobi303 Essentially I want the same effect as vector of pair

Comment: @SvenNilsson Is the same also true for std::lower_bound

Comment: types are not only to hold data, but to express what you want to do with that data. If you want to sort a vector of pairs, then `vector<unsigned>` is the wrong type

Comment: @Jannat if pair is inefficient, use a struct of two int

Comment: @SvenNilsson [Which is exactly what `std::pair` is](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).

Comment: @JannatArora *For large vectors after testing I* -- You need to post if you're testing an optimized build or "debug", non-optimized build.  If it is not optimized, then your findings are meaningless.  This is especially the case for the Visual Studio set of compilers, where iterator checking in debug builds slows down vector to a crawl in some cases.

Comment: @Gill that is what i thought too

Comment: Re: "`std::sort` is going to sort `vec` entirely" -- this is the wrong level of analysis. `std::sort` takes a pair of iterators and sorts the data that the iterators point at. If you pass iterators that run through all of `vec` then `std::sort` will sort all of `vec`. If you pass iterators that run through the even-indexed members of `vec` then `std::sort` will sort the even-indexed members.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do:

```
std::vector<unsigned> vec = {5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4};
auto pair_view = ranges::view::zip(vec | ranges::view::stride(2),
                                   vec | ranges::view::drop(1) |  ranges::view::stride(2));

ranges::sort(pair_view);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8e324b8f9002c5aa)

Comment: Simply elegant! ... :-)

Comment: A note that this can be done manuallty, or with boost, may help people who don't want to use C++20 yet.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not so efficient but a working solution would be:

```
std::vector<std::pair<size_t,unsigned int>> temp_vec;
temp_vec.reserve(vec.size());
for(size_t i=0;i<vec.size();++i){
    temp_vec.emplace_back(i,vec[i]);
}
std::sort(temp_vec.begin(),temp_vec.end(),[](auto l,auto r){
    return /* some condition based on l.first and r.first*/;
});
std::transfrom(temp_vec.begin(),temp_vec.end(),vec.begin(),[](auto item){
     return item.second;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented by calling `std::sort` with a custom iterator, that skips indices and with a custom comparison fucnction, that compares the adjacent value if current comparison is equal.

The custom iterator can be built on top of the existing iterator. A construct like that is called an iterator adaptor. You don't need to write such iterator adaptor from scratch yourself, since boost has already done the hard work. You can use `boost::adaptors::strided`. If you cannot use boost, then you can re-implement it.

---

Much simpler solution would be to use pairs, though. Or better yet, a structure if there are sensible names for the members.

Answer (score 0):

Not the fastest sorting algorithm but it works:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<unsigned> vec = { 5, 6, 5, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4 };

    if (vec.size() > 1 && vec.size() % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (size_t i1 = 0, j1 = i1 + 1; i1 < vec.size() - 1 && j1 < vec.size(); i1+=2, j1 = i1+1)
        { 
            for (size_t i2 = i1 + 2, j2 = i2 + 1; i2 < vec.size() - 1 && j2 < vec.size(); i2 += 2, j2 = i2 + 1)
            {
                if (vec[i1] > vec[i2] || (vec[i1] == vec[i2] && vec[j1] > vec[j2]))
                {
                    std::swap(vec[i1], vec[i2]);
                    std::swap(vec[j1], vec[j2]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

[[On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d06337a7235ac58)]